# mat-select options display outside of any containers the mat-select is in

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use material angular for fancier forms but it just keeps doing weird things with the select.
[Screenshot of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PePQY.jpg)

The options of the select are displayed down to the left while the select is in the middle column.
and if an option is selected then it won't show up inside the select(also in screenshot)

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="partForm"  (ngSubmit)="submitPart()" id="partform">
      <p class="heading">Create a Part</p>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Select part-type:</mat-label>

        <mat-select formControlName="PartType">

          <mat-option *ngFor="let partType of forgingService.availablePartTypes">

            <div [matTooltip]="partType.desc">{{partType.type}}</div>

          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Select material:</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="Material">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let material of forgingService.availableMaterials" >

            <app-material [Mat]="material"></app-material>

          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```

using angular 15.2.8

Edit: It seems the mat-option elements are added to the end of the HTML for some reason

Comment: It's looks like you have a problem with the .css, check how import the angular theme or you have a .css that override the cdk-overlay-container. It's possible also the verion of angular and material angular will be not compatible, check the version of @material/angular and @angular/cdk

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to add a value to "option"

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let partType of forgingService.availablePartTypes" [value]="partyType.type">
```

Should do the trick. Same for the second mat-options.

Comment: That solved the issue with the values not being in the box when selected thank you. but the other problem is still there